# Apple care - product registration

Tags: macbook-pro, applecare

I brought a macbook pro last year (on the 24th of March 2012). and today i tried to buy a apple care protection plan. When i tried to register the apple care protection plan i got an message which states;

> ```
> We apologize for any inconvenience, but registration for this product requires additional documentation. Please submit your proof of purchase for review by Apple. If your registration is accepted, your product will be covered.
> ```

Therefore, i uploaded the receipt that i got from a local store. Is it the receipt that they are expecting ?

And, they have told me that they will get back to me within 24-48 hours. If they get late i will not be able to register the apple care protection plan before the deadline.

What will hapen if apple gets delayed to reply to me and as a result i fail to register the apple care protection plan before the deadline (24th March 2013). Will the apple care protection plan get cancelled and i will not be able to get apple's support for 2 years from now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a reseller sells Macs, they are supposed to report the sales data properly back to Apple. If this data is not reported, the "sales date" in Apple's system is the date the reseller bought it, not the date you bought it from them. Apple is requesting your original proof of purchase, which you've provided.

In general, if it is clearly shown that you have attempted to purchase AppleCare within your one-year period you should have no issues getting this registered, even if the date creeps slighly past the one-year mark. A good option as well is to visit a local Apple Store if you have any issues, with any documentation. I have seen store Geniuses and Managers go out of their way to ensure issues like this are resolved appropriately.